# Не работает ini конфигурация для uwsgi Flask

Tags: nginx, flask, uwsgi

получил проблему при деплое апи на flask.
Использование следующей команды для старта дает успешный результат.

```
uwsgi --socket 0.0.0.0:5000 --protocol=http -w wsgi:app
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Но используя команду принимающую настройки из INI файла, работать перестаёт

```
uwsgi --ini api.ini
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Предполагаю проблема в сокете но не смог найти путь решения.

Из лога подключений:

```
[10/Dec/2023:00:53:43 +0300] "GET /api/v1/subs/ HTTP/1.1" 502 166 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:120.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/120.0"
```

INI:

```
[uwsgi]
module = wsgi:app

master = true
processes = 10

socket = api.sock
chmod-socket = 660
vacuum = true

die-on-term = true
```

.service

```
[Unit]
Description=uWSGI instance to serve panthers api
After=network.target

[Service]
User=root
Group=www-data
WorkingDirectory=/root/api_dir
ExecStart=uwsgi --ini api.ini
RestartSec=10
Restart=always

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Nginx

```
server {
        listen 80;
        server_name testers.online;
        location / {
            include uwsgi_params;
            uwsgi_pass unix:/root/api_dir/api.sock;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Ну покажите содержимое ini хотя бы наверное?

Comment: Ну а где в этом вашем ini прослушивание порта 5000?

Comment: @andreymal я использую в связке с nginx, возможно ошибку и там допускаю.

Comment: То есть в uwsgi у вас нету порта 5000, в nginx тоже нету порта 5000, а при этом вы в браузере зачем-то пытаетесь открыть порт 5000? Нелогично как-то

Comment: @andreymal при попытке законектиться на домен или адрес без порта 502 Bad Gateway

Comment: Значит читайте в логе ошибок nginx, по какой причине он решил выдать ошибку 502

Comment: Хотя как минимум сразу можно наугад сказать, что nginx не имеет (и не должен иметь) доступа к каталогу `/root`. Пускать кого угодно в каталог суперпользователя — плохая идея. Запускать от имени суперпользователя программы, которым на самом деле не нужны права суперпользователя — ОЧЕНЬ плохая идея

Comment: @andreymal по поводу рута я знаю. Оказалось что у юзера под которым стартовал nginx не было прав жить и двигаться. Поменял юзера - всё заработало. Спасибо за ответы и уделённое время